# Filtering values in one dataframe if they are within a specified range of values in another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, left-join

We have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(10, 12, 52, 102))
df2 <- data.frame(y = c(11, 15, 30, 130))
```

We want to filter rows in `df1$x` if they are within plus or minus 10 values of any value in 'df2$y'

so the result of the filter on `df1` would be :

```r
data.frame(x = c(10, 12))
```

because 10 and 12 in `df1$x` are within +/- 10 of 11 and 15 in `df2$y`.

If we wanted to only filter rows that matched "exactly", we could use `dplyr::left_join`. But how can we do this if we want to use a range of values (i.e., +/- 10) as described above?

Answer (score 2):

We may use `power_inner_join`

```
library(powerjoin)
library(dplyr)
power_inner_join(df1, df2, by = c(~ .x$x <= (.y$y + 10 ) & 
     .x$x >= (.y$y - 10))) %>% 
   distinct(x)
   x
1 10
2 12
```

---

Or do a non-equi join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[setDT(df2)[, .(ystart = y-10, yend = y+10)], 
    flag := TRUE, on = .(x >= ystart, x <= yend)]
df1[as.logical(flag), .(x)]
       x
   <num>
1:    10
2:    12
```

Comment: Not sure if this works as intended always, but a rolling join might be able to do it too `df1[df1[df2, on=c("x"="y"), roll=10, rollends=c(TRUE,TRUE), .I, nomatch=0L]]` ?

Comment: @thelatemail  I didn't test on other cases.  You may be correct

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(sqldf)
#> Loading required package: gsubfn
#> Loading required package: proto
#> Loading required package: RSQLite
#> Warning: package 'RSQLite' was built under R version 4.1.2

df1 <- data.frame(x = c(10, 12, 52, 102))
df2 <- data.frame(y = c(11, 15, 30, 130))

sqldf('
select
  distinct
  a.*
from
  df1 a
  join df2 b
    on a.x between b.y - 10 and b.y + 10
')
#>    x
#> 1 10
#> 2 12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>